# Stylesheets Rules Return Null only on iphone?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, cordova, safari

I'm trying to read styleSheet rules through JavaScript but both `document.styleSheets[0].rules` and `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` return `Null`.
To clarify:
if the loaded css looks like this:

```
.example{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Using Javascript, if I call document.styleSheets[0].rules assuming the css is the first on in the html file, I should get the rule data. But that doesn't happen.

This issue only happens on iOS. It works fine on Safari and also works fine on Android.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @abney317 I tried adding some clarification. I don't know how to explain it better and I apologize. The issue is if you have a css file in your html, you should be able, using JS, to get the rules list using document.styleSheets[0].cssRules. It works correct on every browser except on cordova IOS. I'm guessing it might be either a limitation on cordova iOS or something else I don't know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the issue. It appears to be caused by a combination of reasons. As this is the first time I use my code with cordova iOS, I think I didn't fix XHR known issue with WkWebview correctly on the first time I added the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr plugin. I think it wasn't added correctly. So I had to remove the iOS platform and I had and start over. I added cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr again and made sure I had:

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

in the config file and style rules showed as they should.

Comment: you guys saved my life.
It's weird problem. It works well on Cordova and iOS 13. but for at least iOS14.6, errors to read cssRules.